# Is there a php function for using the source code of another web page?

Tags: php, function

I want to create a PHP script that grabs the content of a website. So let's say it grabs all the source code for that website and I say which lines of code I need.

Is there a function in PHP that allows you too do this or is it impossible?

Disclaimer: I'm not going to use this for any illegal purposes at all and not asking you too write any code, just tell me if its possible and if you can how I'd go about doing it. Also I'm just asking in general, not for any specific reason. Thanks! :)

Comment: The content of a website (which you can grab) is something different from the source code for that website (which you cannot).

Comment: I mean the HTML, not any server side source

Comment: Even simpler is `file_get_contents("http://remote/page")` usually. But that's fit for extracting HTML. I'm not sure that's what you meant with grabbing source or lines of code. (Receiving the code from remote .php scripts is not possible; unless specifically prepared.)

Comment: @Jon: The content *is* the source code, for a web page. If you generate your web page with PHP or ASP or Perl or Ruby or Python or whatever, then that's different :P

Comment: No I just mean the HTML, that's available to anyone. No server side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file('http://the.url.com')` returns an array of lines from a url.

so for the 24th line do this:

```
$lines = file('http://www.whatever.com');
echo $lines[23];
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a horrible idea, but here we go:

- Use `file_get_contents()` to get the file. You cannot get the source if the web server first processes it, so you may need to use an extension like `.txt`. Unless you password protect the file, obviously anybody can get it.
- Use `explode()` with the `\n` delimiter to split the source code into lines.
- Use `array_slice()` to get the lines you need.
- `eval()` the code.

Note: if you just want the HTML output, then ignore the bit about the source in step 1 and obviously you can skip the whole `eval()` thing.